# Tool to take screenshot of a specific HTML element of a webpage

Tags: windows, firefox, screenshot

In order to get a dashboard (including Flash charts) from a local web portal and show them in PowerPoint presentations, I need a tool that allows me to take **a screenshot of the content of a specific HTML tag** of my browser (a unique ID can be provided to know which tag is concerned).

Requirements:

- Works with Firefox 17
- Can be used on Windows XP and Windows 7

Best to have:

- No administrator account needed
- Can resize the screen
- The screen should be available into the clipboard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use inspect element to get the "Unique Selector", then input that into the firefox console (hit shift-f2) and type in `screenshot --selector <unique_selector> --clipboard` to save to clipboard or replace --clipboard with the filename to save it.

In short, you can do this in Firefox with no addons whatsoever.

Comment: It looks very interesting, unfortunately the clipboard option doesn't seem to work with my firefox version (17.0.6). [The syntax working](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/11/02/take-screenshots-straight-from-firefoxs-developer-toolbar/) is `screenshot <filename> [delay] [fullpage] [node]`. And at the moment I don't succeed in makink node parameter works.

Comment: The fact that you need delay is wierd. I usually use filename and fullscreen, but using the node name off inspector worked when I messed with it.

Comment: If you specify no filename nor `--clipboard` flag, Firefox will save it as an image in your Downloads directory with some default name. So you can just use `screenshot --selector <unique_selector>` actually.

Comment: Yeah. I'd tailored the commands to the user's needs tho. He explicitly wanted it on the clipboard.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek He wanted it in clipboard as "Best to have". If it doesn't work with his browser, I've given an alternative.